# What happened to "the last seminary" website

Tags: reference-request

It used to be in the web "my last seminary" / "summer seminary site" with a lot of links for topics on philosophical and theological issues. Does somebody know to where it migrated or mirrors?

Comment: can you provide any more details? was it for a particular denomination? was it a dot com/org/net?

Comment: if you know the old url you could try https://archive.org/web/

Comment: archive.org found: http://lastseminary.com/
last seminary
capture(s) from 2009 to 2014 | Site stats. But when I clicked on it, it redirected twice (301, permanently moved) and went nowhere. Is that likely to be the site you're looking for?

Comment: @disciple. Thanks! I found it, but I am facing a problem to load it: bad gateway. Do you know how to overcame it? Some similar web?

Comment: Found Aug 17 at www.lastseminary.com . Both lastseminary.com and apollos.ws now redirect there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fortunately, this was a temporary problem which is now solved**

The site you are looking for has used two domain names over the last 15 years or so: [lastseminary.com](http://lastseminary.com) and [apollos.ws](http://apollos.ws). At present, either of these names, with or without a prepended www, should resolve to www.lastseminary.com where the content is.

It appears there was an error redirecting from one url to another. The primary site has been apollos.ws for the last several years, and a lot of the content should be available on archive.org if you ever have trouble finding it on lastseminary in the future. Most of my original answer is no longer valid. If you are interested in the technical details, it should still be in the edit history.

A description on the site (as originally found at archive.org):

> What is Apollos.ws
>
> Apollos.ws is a resource for Christian academics. We organize audio,
>   video, books, and articles related to Philosophy of Religion,
>   Apologetics, and Biblical Studies. This site is an ideal research tool
>   for graduate and post-graduate students.

The site is quite limited in describing and 'selling' itself. As an example, the easiest way I know to find their 'about us' page is to search for it. If you include the quotes in the search, you will get only one result. In my opinion it is a very useful reference site.

Comment: Now I can open.

Comment: Archive.org claimed one of the pages on apollo.ws is available on the web. I hope the site is only temporarily down (for me, at least), and much of my answer proves to be wrong. In the future, you should be aware that it is customary not to accept an answer for a day or two, so that everyone in the world has the opportunity to write a good answer and have a chance to get it accepted. Of course you can un-accept an answer if a better one comes along later.

Comment: Today, apollos.ws redirects to /www.lastseminary.com . I will keep an eye on the situation and intend to update the answer to confirm this was a temporary problem.